# StreamConn unsubscribe() and close() appear not to work (AlpacaAPI), seeking opinions

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-3.7, python-asyncio, python-multithreading

Just getting into working with the Alpaca API (also uses the Polygon IO service) and ran into the following issue, which appears like it should be straightforward, but I'm stuck. The code initializes and prints all the information expected correctly. The problem is that when I call "unsubscribe" there's no error message and the messages just keep on coming.

Interesting thing is that I've also tried calling deregister() and even just close() - all to no avail. I've also tried adjusting the patterns in various ways - again, with no error thrown, hard to figure out. But the line "Closing connection for " plus the ticker symbol just keeps on coming and coming and coming.

I'm suspicious that the calls are getting lost in the StreamConn / asyncio event loop somewhere and simply aren't being run, but I'm not really sure how to best troubleshoot that. Any thoughts would be welcome. Python 3.7, in case it isn't obvious.

Note that I'm not doing anything interesting with this script apart from printing out the stream data as it comes in, as way to understand why I'm not able to close the connection. The documentation states (and code shows) that we should be able to subscribe to additional channels mid-run, but so far that has not worked either. Ultimate desired end state is the ability to subscribe to additional channels and unsubscribe from existing channels in an ongoing manner. As the libraries use asyncio, should be already manageable using threads, one would think...

Alpaca's StreamConn source is here: https://github.com/alpacahq/alpaca-trade-api-python/blob/master/alpaca_trade_api/stream2.py The Alpaca version extends the original Polygon class, here: https://github.com/alpacahq/alpaca-trade-api-python/blob/master/alpaca_trade_api/polygon/streamconn.py

```
from alpaca_trade_api import StreamConn
from alpaca_config import AlpacaAPIConfig
import datetime

script_start = datetime.datetime.now()
conn = StreamConn(AlpacaAPIConfig.get_public_api_key(), AlpacaAPIConfig.get_secret_key())
symbols = ['AAPL', 'MSFT']


async def handle_signal(channel, symbol, value):
    if (datetime.datetime.now() - script_start).seconds > 30:
        print('Closing connection for ' + str(symbol))
        await conn.unsubscribe([r'^T.' + str(symbol), r'^AM.' + str(symbol)])
    else:
        print(str(channel) + '.' + str(symbol))
        print(str(value))
        print(' ')


@conn.on(r'^AM.*$', symbols)  # AM. denotes minute bars, symbols is the list of tickers to listen for
async def on_bar(conn, channel, bar):
    symbol = bar.symbol
    close = float(bar.close)
    print('-- AM Hit --')
    await handle_signal(channel, symbol, close)


@conn.on(r'^T.*$', symbols)  # T. denotes a trade event, symbols is the list of tickers to listen for
async def on_trade(conn, channel, trade):
    symbol = str(trade.symbol)
    price = str(trade.price)
    print('-- T Hit --')
    await handle_signal(channel, symbol, price)


def kickoff():
    conn.run([
        'T.*',
        'AM.*'
    ])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    kickoff()
```

Copy of the output, just in case it's helpful:

```
-- T Hit --
T.AAPL
382.31
 
-- T Hit --
T.AAPL
382.31
 
-- AM Hit --
AM.AAPL
382.31
 
-- AM Hit --
AM.MSFT
213.32
 
-- T Hit --
T.MSFT
213.45
 
-- T Hit --
Closing connection for AAPL
-- T Hit --
Closing connection for AAPL
-- T Hit --
Closing connection for AAPL
-- T Hit --
Closing connection for MSFT
-- T Hit --
Closing connection for AAPL
-- T Hit --
Closing connection for AAPL
```

UPDATED
Apparently, `.run` and `.subscribe / .unsubscribe` don't play well together. I changed the `kickoff()` function to the following:

```
async def kickoff():
    await conn.subscribe(['T.AAPL', 'T.MSFT', 'AM.AAPL', 'AM.MSFT'])
```

and the `__main__()` function to:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    loop.create_task(kickoff())
    loop.run_forever()
```

Now, using `.subscribe()` instead of `.run`, the ticker behavior is as expected (stops when `.unsubscribe()` is called). However, now I'll have to figure out the event loop part...